# How to animate object 360 in ARToolKit in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, augmented-reality, artoolkit

Currently I am working on the **Augmented Reality** and it works perfectly for me but I wanted to know how to animate the object in `ARToolkit` my issue is animation is not working for me

What i did i have created a fbx file from blender then i have converted into the .osgt format then i have converted to .osg format

Can any one help me out how we can animation the object in ARToolkit for iOS ?

Comment: Hi, are you sure about the file format ORG? Never heard of that. ARToolKit5 used OSG (OpenSceneGraph) to work with 3D models and manipulate them.

Comment: @Thor_Bux Yes i am sorry yes it's OSG Filer it's my mistake how to generate OSg file ?

Comment: Hi, it is not about generating OSG files. OSG is a framework that is capable of loading different 3D model types. .obj file for example are loadable and can be rendered using OSG. OSG also supports animated 3D-Models.
However, I fear I still don't get your question.

Comment: @Thor_Bux what i need to do is i need to animate the object to 360 degree automatically

Comment: how we can animate the object in ARToolkit file i used OBJ file that is working correctly but how we can animate the object? like in the example of like Plan in ARToolkit

Comment: Well, ARToolKit isn't a 3D modeling or animating tool. It gives you the location of a Trackable which is visible in your video stream. You can then use this location and render a 3D model to that location. If you would like to animate a 3D object use Blender or 3DS Max or something else and export the animated model. Then you can load it into ARToolKit. Or use Unity3D with ARToolKit plugin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147585/discussion-between-mayank-patel-and-thor-bux).

Comment: @Thor_Bux i have created a OSG File from the FBX from blender but in the app animation is not working can you help me ?

Comment: @Thor_Bux how we can do animation ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate an .OSG file from whatever 3D Modelling/Animation tool you are using. You can use that .OSG file together with ARToolKit5.

For export from Blender have a look here: https://github.com/cedricpinson/osgexport

Then you need to read through this C-Interface that ARToolKit5 uses to interact with OpenSceneGraph(OSG) http://artoolkit.github.io/artoolkit5/doc/apiref/arosg_h/index.html

There are several arOSGSetModelAnimation* functions that you can use to manipulate the animation.

Have a look at the Android example: https://github.com/artoolkit/artoolkit5/tree/master/AndroidStudioProjects/ARNativeOSGProj
The C-Classes show you how you can load and use .OSG files with ARToolKit.

However, you need to use C on iOS and you cannot use Swift.

==Edit==

This question here gives some background regarding .FBX usage. 
[Import FBX to ARToolKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30598005/import-fbx-to-artoolkit)

In short .FBX is not supported and one should use the OSG commandline tool to convert .FBX to .OSG

--- Personal note ---

From my experience is easier to use the Unity3D plugin of ARToolKit5 or ARToolKit6 do you animations with Unity3D and export an iOS app.

Comment: Check this is my 3D animation file (osg file) https://ufile.io/lfp20 can you check it is not working at my side

Comment: but .obj file does not support the animation it is simple showing 3D object i want to show object with animation

Comment: can you send me a sample who has an obj file with animation ? so i can try to configure my side

Comment: Sorry my bad, there is some such as an .OSG format and Blender can export it. Also, you are right .OBJ does not support animation. Corrected answer.

Comment: I tried my self i have converted FBX file into OSG format but animation is not working thats why i am asking you how we can achieve the animation ?

Comment: Please see my comments i already have a tool and i installed openscence graph i know i am converting fbx to org conversation thats why i am telling you animation is not working that is my point  ufile.io/lfp20  see this is OSG file that i converted from command line

Comment: what is the issue if i am not able to show the animation on project Here is osg file check this  ufile.io/lfp20

Comment: The only think I can say to that is that in the Android Project the .OSG has animation as well and there is works. (OSG: https://github.com/artoolkit/artoolkit5/tree/master/AndroidStudioProjects/ARNativeOSGProj/aRNativeOSG/src/main/assets/OSG)
Android Project: https://github.com/artoolkit/artoolkit5/tree/master/AndroidStudioProjects/ARNativeOSGProj

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148010/discussion-between-mayank-patel-and-thor-bux).